# Why can't 'return' return the value from the function?

Tags: python, recursion, return, pascals-triangle

Here is my code:

```
def getRow(rowIndex):

    if rowIndex == 0:
        return [1]
    if rowIndex == 1:
        return [1,1]

    def f(n,r):
        if n == 1:
            print(r)
            return r
        r = [1]+[r[i] + r[i+1] for i in range(len(r)-1)]+[1]
        f(n-1,r)

    return f(rowIndex,[1,1])

print(getRow(4))
```

That `print(r)` function worked perfectly and gave the right answer, however, the `return r` statement just didn't work at all. Anyone knows why is this happening?

Desired output: `[1,4,6,4,1]`

Actual output: `null`

I would like to know why doesn't the `return r` statement in the `f` function return anything through the `return f(rowIndex,[1,1])` statement.

Comment: You need to `return f(n-1,r)`

Comment: Your question is not clear, because your statements "the right answer" and "just didn't work at all" are vague. You showed your code and the input--now clearly state the desired output, actual output, and just how the actual output is wrong. Show the full traceback for any errors. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

> the return r statement just didn't work at all

If the print works, then the `return` works. However, it only works **when `n == 1`**.

In all other cases, your function will essentially `return None` (not `null`) since you have no other `return` statement within the `f` function body.

Perhaps you can try `return f(n-1,r)` rather than simply calling the function and ignoring the return result